# ElasticSearch Spring boot does not sort by relevant data

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch in spring boot project. The problem is that when I am querying data with Elasticsearch's API it is giving sorted (by relevant first) data. But when I am using `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` in my spring boot project it is not giving me sorted data by relevance.

Here is my code

```
    val searchQuery = NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(matchQuery("keywords", "searchQuery"))
        .build()
    val results= elasticsearchRestTemplate.search(searchQuery, ESSolution::class.java).map{it.content}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check the score values of the returned SearchHit objects?